# Square PoS Android Web auto_return

Tags: javascript, square-connect

I'm trying to build a Web App for use on an Android device which initiates a payment.  I'm doing this by placing a button and using the Intent schema, with javascript. It looks something like this:

```
var intent = "intent:#Intent;action=com.squareup.pos.action.CHARGE;package=com.squareup;S.browser_fallback_url=" + payment.fallback_url + ";S.com.squareup.pos.WEB_CALLBACK_URI=" + payment.callback_url + ";S.com.squareup.pos.CLIENT_ID=" + payment.client_id + ";S.com.squareup.pos.API_VERSION=v2.0;i.com.squareup.pos.TOTAL_AMOUNT=" + payment.total_amount + ";S.com.squareup.pos.CURRENCY_CODE=" + payment.currency_code + ";S.com.squareup.pos.TENDER_TYPES=com.squareup.pos.TENDER_CARD;end"
```

The process should be as frictionless as possible, and therefore I'd like to skip the receipt, and automatically return to my app as soon as the transaction is done.  Looks like this is possible in iOS with the [additional payment options](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/web-api-ios#additionalpaymentoptions) - but I don't see if that's available in Android.

Is there a way to pass this option from a web app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option yet on Android for skipping the receipt in the POS API. However, you can enable skipping a receipt on each device by logging into Point of Sale,  navigating to Settings -> Signature and Receipt and toggling the "Skip Receipt Screen" option.

Comment: Is that also the case for auto_return? (is there any other way to automatically return to my app once the transaction is complete?)

Comment: There is an auto_return paramter for Android, which can be added to your intent url string with "l.com.squareup.pos.AUTO_RETURN_TIMEOUT_MS={your desired timeout in ms here}"  (that first letter is an L for long). The timeout parameter has a minimum of 3200L and a maximum of 10000L (must be between 3.2 and 10 seconds). Unfortunately this is missing from the documentation website, but it should be added soon.